# OpenCV: Matrix error message "Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat" while not using matrices

Tags: exception, opencv, image-scaling

I get an matrix-related error message/exception from OpenCV while capturing and scaling image data although I do not use a matrix. That's my code at the moment:

```
if (data->capture->grab()) // capture something from already opened device
{
    if (data->capture->retrieve(grabFrame,0)) // get the frame
    {
        CvSize size;

        size.width=data->config.width;
        size.height=data->config.height;
        nextFrame=cvCreateImage(size,32,0);
        resFrame=cvCreateImage(size,32,0); // predefined default sizes to scale the image to...
        if ((nextFrame) && (resFrame))
        {
            cvResize(&grabFrame,nextFrame,cv::INTER_AREA); // scale the image to the predefined size

--> here the Exception is thrown!

            cvCvtColor(nextFrame,resFrame,CV_BGR2RGB);
            ...
        }
        if (nextFrame) cvReleaseImage(&nextFrame);
    }
}
```

The exact output from OpenCV is this:

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat, file /builddir/build/BUILD/> OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 646
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /builddir/build/BUILD/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:646: error: (-5) Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat
>
> Aborted

So what am I doing wrong here in my stupid and simple scaling operation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I need to use cvQueryFrame() to get a frame in correct format.